# How I can use Drush for portal deployment and redeployment?

Tags: drush, composer

I have downloaded Composer on a Windows 11 computer. I have installed Drush with `composer require drush/drush`, or maybe `composer global require drush/drush`.

As I haven't mentioned any specific version, the 12.x release got installed in my system.

Somehow there were some installation issue over my office Internet network when I'd installed Drush. I think not every module been pulled, because of that whenever I ran Drush I had this error.

> [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed

So I ran once `composer global require drupal/core`.

I had certain issues while installing Drush. I had followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587828/install-of-laravel-laravel-failed. Also I have uncommented `;extension=gd` in the php.ini file.

After all the steps I tried, I am able to run Drush command from the command prompt.

I am using `XAMPP`. I don't know how I can utilize `drush` for the portal deployment / re-deployment.

Comment: Whenever I run `drush` in my system I get this `hint` at the last line after help page of command reference been printed for `cmd` execution. `the line - ! [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.`

Comment: Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a local dependency. No global Drush. Global Drupal core also won't fix it. https://www.drush.org/12.x/install/

Comment: Please use DDEV or Lando instead of MAMP/XAMP or any other yesteryear stack.

Comment: With DDEV you need nothing else than Docker and DDEV installed on your system. Everything else (PHP, Composer, MySQL, Apache/Nginx) will be provided by Docker.

Comment: @leymannx I have followed the ***answer*** of the drupal forum feed,- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765515/ddev-does-not-seem-to-be-instaling-drupal-was-working-before So by now, I am able to set some site over ***drupal config wizard*** after `ddev launch`. ***SO*** now, how can I set  ***drupal root***, for the `drush` command.

Comment: You use `ddev drush` instead of `drush` and don't care about any root.

Answer (score 0):

Drush changed the install method somewhen after Drush 9: https://www.drush.org/12.x/install/ - it will no longer accept a global drush, but you need to add `./vendor/bin` to your path:

> 2. Execution. Change your working directory to your project root, and call Drush via `vendor/bin/drush`. To make this easier, append `./vendor/bin` to the end of your `$PATH`; this allows you to call Drush via drush once your working directory is set. If you only have only one Drupal codebase on your system, you may put `/path/to/vendor/bin/drush` in your `$PATH`; if you do this, then it is not necessary to set your working directory before calling Drush.

Comment: come on guys, it's still the right answer ;)

Comment: Didn't vote down but I think OP actually is able to run Drush and the question in the very last sentence is: I don't know how I can utilize Drupal (Drush?) for the portal deployment.

Comment: Jea, the question changed a lot since the first post

Comment: Yes it has changed since I put my first version of the feed. I took your answer to the count. ***HOWEVER***, my system is not `Linux` based, it is a `Windows 11` based system rather, so let me go by the comments suggested over my question. I hope it is not that easy as you've suggested. I think all it needs is a `container` & the ground system either `hypervisor` or `wsl2` and the `containerized app` as a whole, so my `drush` works as expected.

Comment: I made a complete document for utilizing `drush` in a local system and uploaded it in ***Google Drive***. Here is the link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kb1lhV3XYrwC1HXJXqHR4D_cuQEHqVSD/view?usp=drive_link